# How do you add a list id to a newly created HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I dynamically add text inputs to a table while assigning the same list id?
My code is currently:

```
function addspeakers(){
    for(j=0; j<10;j++){
    var cellid='inp'+cellnum;
    input=document.getElementById('sprow').appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
    input.placeholder='Country '+cellnum;
    input.id='inp'+cellnum;
    // add to list input.addtolist(countries);
    cellnum++;
    }
return
}
```

all it does is add 10 text inputs to a list however these lists have drop down menus...
This is the code for the datalist:

```
<datalist id='countries'>
```

and the text input elements should be created looking like this:

```
<table id='splist'>
  <tr>
    <td id='sprow'>
      <input list='countries' placeholder='Country 1' id='inp1'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What do I need to add it to the list id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setAttribute` to set the property on the element.

```
input.setAttribute('list', 'countries');
```

Also since `list` is a not a default attribute of the element, but a custom attribute.

You can use `data-*` ( which is custom attributes)

```
<input data-list='countries'

input.setAttribute('data-list', 'countries');
```

Comment: thank you! i used both list and data-list attributes and the list one worked perfectly :D setAttribute is super helpful i just read about it!

Comment: @splch12 Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to assign it like your other variables:

```
input.list='countries';
```

Also, you never use `cellid`, and your `return` is unnecessary ;)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank for for letting me know about cellid (turns out is was also unnecessary :P and thanks for letting me know about return!